# Is it possible to re-enable a prompt in Outlook when deleting an email from Inbox?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a Windows 7 machine and I used to get a prompt in Outlook 2010 whenever I deleted an email from Inbox. It was "Are you sure you want to delete this email?". But I accidentally hit "Do not show this in future" checkbox and now I have went through almost all the settings that I can think of but I cannot find where to re-enable this setting from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you delete an item and move it from Inbox to Deleted folder, we may not see the confirmation dialog. If we permanently delete a message or delete one from Deleted folder, we will get the confirmation.

To re-enable it, please go to File > Options > Advanced. Under Other section, select the option “Prompt for confirmation before permanently deleting items.

[image]

Comment: I did that already but I was wondering if there was a way to restore a prompt when we delete an email FROM Inbox.

Comment: If you delete a message, we may not see the confirmation dialog. If you accidentally delete an email, you can simply move it from Deleted folder back to Inbox.